# What is the best way to reload view when ajax success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a `add button`. When user click this button,I was call `ajax function` to controller method.After doing something in controller,return `view model` with user added data.

I reloaded view model after ajax `success()` Like=>

```
success: function (data) {                    
                    $("#divLibrarySidePanel").html(data);
                },
```

My html structure is

```
<body>

        <table border="0" style="border-spacing: 5px 0px; width: 100%;border:0px solid grey;" id="divLibrarySidePanel">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 100%; height: 100%">
.
.
.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

It reloaded successful.But when i check in browser's inspect.It show me like=>

[image]

It was duplicated table structure.Where i was wrong and which way is to best reload view?

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, you can use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

```
$("#divLibrarySidePanel").replaceWith($("<div>", {
        html: data
    }).find('#divLibrarySidePanel'));
```

As per snapshot, `data` return HTML fragment which contains the target element. thus `.find()` to extract only desired portion.

Or, You can go through the traditional route of submitting `FORM`

Comment: @Satpal.I was tested with your answer.It error occur "data.find is not a function".What is worng?

Comment: Still error occur.It show all blank. I think it was return empty. Can you more detail explain which way is to reload view.Thank you @Satpal.

Comment: This answer fixed the duplicate table error but all of script not work after that.:(

Comment: @Jze, This is expected as you are replacing the DOM elements, event handlers associated with them is also removed. In this condition you can use  [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like `$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)`